# jersey + json parsing

Tags: json, jackson, jersey, jackson-databind

I have the following controller:

```
@POST
@Path("endpoint")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON+ ";charset=utf-8"})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8", "application/javascript;charset=utf-8"})
public void postData(@Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
                      @Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context UriInfo uriInfo,
                      JSONData postedData) {
   
}
```

My related pom dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

The version resolved in the dependencies is 2.17 for all the dependencies.

I am registering the JacksonFeature class in the properties

```
jersey.config.server.provider.classnames=org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature
```

And I get the following exception when performing a request: (the JSONData class is very simple by now, only a String property annotated with lombok to generate getter and setters)

> 2020-12-07 12:31:56,910 ERROR [jersey-server-managed-async-executor-0]
> JsonExceptionMapper - at
> es.colbenson.sb.ws.JsonExceptionMapper.toResponse(JsonExceptionMapper.java:28)
> Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.BeanUtil.okNameForSetter(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/AnnotatedMethod;)Ljava/lang/String;
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.findNameForDeserialization(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:875)
> ~[jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]

I've also tried registering the *JacksonFeature* class on my application constructor:

```
register(JacksonFeature)
```

But I can get this working. Any thoughts?

Also I can see this in the exception Stack Trace, which seems to be pointing to a jackson-databind-2.9.8 inside, but I'm not sure if it is a kind of conflict...

> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addSetterMethod(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:620)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]   at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addMethods(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:535)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]   at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collectAll(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:309)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]   at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getPropertyMap(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:287)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]   at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getProperties(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:170)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]

Comment: Are those _all_ your dependencies? Whenever you see a NoSuchMethodError, it is almost always a version compatibility issue, where you have overlapping dependencies and they are of different versions. If the problem is not with your dependencies, then it is probably with the server, where the server already has a jar that you also are using in your project, but they are different versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

And add this other

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Then register this provider:

```
jersey.config.server.provider.classnames=com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
```

It seems a matter of using the proper jackson binder for this version of jersey